# How can I add a table of contents in R Markdown?

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I'm having a hard time trying to add a table of contents in R Markdown.
I want the table of contents to be on the left side of the document. 
I tried this code, but it didn't work for me (when I knitr the document, it works fine, but the TOC is not available):

```
---
title: "Relatório VANT - P&D"
author: "Empresa: XXXX"
date: "Data: 24/05/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float: true
---
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to indent `toc`, e.g.

```
---
title: "Relatório VANT - P&D"
author: "Empresa: XXXX"
date: "Data: 24/05/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
   toc: true
   toc_float: true
---

# h1

# h2

# h2.2
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked very well for me. One thing I saw is that there is an option ```toc_depth```. I read the default is ```3```, but I don't understand very well what it controls. Do you know anything about it? Thanks again!